# How to build a JSON object in select query in Objection.js

Tags: objection.js

I have a "location" jsonb type column in table "Ads". It stores values like these:

```
{"lat": 33.742001, 
"lng": -117.823639, 
"zip": "92780", 
"city": "Tustin", 
"state": "CA"}
```

How would I write a select query in Objection.js that returns the same `location` object with only the "city" property in it. I need something like:

```
const ads = AdModel.query().select([
  ...
  ? // <- need the result to be {location: {city: "Tustin"}}
])
```

Basically, I need to build `{location: city: ...}` object and fill in the city name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to build the JSON object I need as such inside `.select([...])` method:

```
raw("json_build_object('city', ??.location->'city') as location", ['Ads'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the $parseDatabaseJson to parse the location field

```
class Ads extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'Ads';
  }
  $parseDatabaseJson(json) {
    json = super.$parseDatabaseJson(json);
    let location = json.location;
    if(location){
       location =  JSON.parse(location)
    }
    return Object.assign({}, json,{ location });
  }
}
```

add the map for selecting specific field

```
Ads.query()
.select('location')
.map((data)=>data.location.city)
.then((city)=>console.log(city));
```

Comment: Thank you for chiming in. I need to build this object in the `select` portion of one query only.